# scaling an SKSpriteNode on it's center

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have an `SKSpriteNode`. I want to make it get bigger and then smaller on its own. So I used a sequence of `SKAction` using `[SKAction scaleTo:]`. It works because the sprite has a bigger width and height, but even though the `anchorPoint` is left to the `(.5, .5)` default, it looks like the sprite gets bigger and moves to the right, as it is wasn't scaling relative to its center. I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong because if it sounds kind of silly to have to adjust the x,y to counter the effect of the scaling.

How do I accomplish scaling relative to its center?

Comment: from my usage it scales fine from the centre - ill post demo code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work as expected

```
SKSpriteNode *myRec = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
myRec.position = CGPointMake(150, 150);
[self addChild:myRec];

[myRec runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                     [SKAction waitForDuration:3.0],
                                     [SKAction scaleTo:2.0 duration:2.0],
                                     [SKAction scaleTo:1.0 duration:2.0],
                                     ]]]];
```

**If your scaling a sprite, make sure the doesn't have extra transparent space off too one side.**

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. It was what I did, except I ran the action on the scene instead of the sprite. I hate it when I feel like an idiot. Thanks for the assist.